# Hyperledger Fabric "evaluateTransaction" ERROR

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to develop a supply chain application using Hyperledger Fabric.

During development, I am using Hyperledger Fabric Test Network and I added a 3. organization using "addOrg3.sh" command. All the codes I used when I start the network are listed below.

```
cd ../test-network
./network.sh down
docker rm -f $(docker ps -aq)

./network.sh up createChannel -ca -s couchdb

cd addOrg3
./addOrg3.sh up -c mychannel -ca -s couchdb

export FABRIC_CFG_PATH=$PWD
../../bin/configtxgen -printOrg Org3MSP > ../organizations/peerOrganizations/org3.example.com/org3.json

cd ..
./network.sh deployCC -ccn SupplychainContract -ccp ../supply-chain/chaincode/ -ccl javascript -ccep "OR('Org1MSP.peer','Org2MSP.peer','Org3MSP.peer')"

export PATH=${PWD}/../bin:$PATH
export FABRIC_CFG_PATH=$PWD/../config/
export CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
export CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org1MSP"
export CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=${PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt
export CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=${PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp
export CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=localhost:7051


cd ../supply-chain/server
rm -r ./wallet/*
node enrollAdmin.js org1 admin adminpw
node enrollAdmin.js org2 admin adminpw
node enrollAdmin.js org3 admin adminpw
chmod 777 wallet
chmod 777 ./wallet/*
```

However, on the running project, while using a wallet belonging to the org3 network, I can run **submitTransaction** command on the chaincode without any problem, but when I try to run the **evaluateTransaction** command, it gives an error as follows.

```
ERROR MESSAGE: 2022-12-07T12:45:38.620Z - error: \[SingleQueryHandler\]: evaluate: message=Query failed. Errors: \["Error: Peer peer0.org3.example.com:11051 is not running chaincode SupplychainContract"\], stack=FabricError: Query failed. Errors: \["Error: Peer peer0.org3.example.com:11051 is not running chaincode SupplychainContract"\]
```

When I call the related method using **submitTransaction** , there is no problem. if i use `docker-compose -f ./compose/docker/docker-compose-org3.yaml up -d` while raising the network, it conflicts with another container produced by **addOrg3.sh** .

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue you are seeing is because the default query handler implementation prefers the client's org peers, and it also returns (either a result or an error) from the first peer it is able to successfully invoke. Your org3 client evaluates the transaction on the org3 peer, which responds with an error saying the smart contract is not deployed there.

The submit implementation is more complex and will use service discovery to identify peer that can satisfy the endorsement policy for a given chaincode, so will not attempt to use the org3 peer.

Using Fabric v2.2, your best options are probably either:

1. Deploy the chaincode on the org3 peer; or
2. Implement your own query handler that provides appropriate behaviour.

This tutorial page describes how to configure an alternative query handler and how to write a custom query handler:

https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-sdk-node/release-2.2/tutorial-query-peers.html

A possible approach would be for your handler to use all network peers and to keep trying peers until it either receives an endorsed response or has tried all available peers.

If you can use Fabric v2.4 (or later), you should consider using the [Fabric Gateway client API](https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-gateway/) instead. This will just work without any additional configuration.